# Find First Non-Blank Cell With Data and Return Value on Separate Tab

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, matching

I am trying to figure out a formula to find the first non blank cell with data on a separate tab from where I need the value returned. I've tried the following formula but no luck: =INDEX(Sheet2!H:H,MATCH(1,Sheet2!A:A=Sheet1!A3)*Sheet2!H:H<>"",0)

On Sheet 1 under column "Value from Sheet 2" I need the value from Sheet 2 under column H that is not blank using Sheet 1's "Name" column as the reference, in this case value "123" is the first non blank cell for name "ABC" on Sheet 2.

[image: Sheet 1]
[image: Sheet 2]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data above, `=sheet2!A$3:A$6=A3` is going to return {true;false;false;true}.

Further, `=NOT(ISBLANK(sheet2!H$3:H$6))` is going to return {false;true;true;true}.

Thus, `=(sheet2!A$3:A$6=A3) * (NOT(ISBLANK(sheet2!H$3:H$6)))` should get you  the array {0;0;0;1}, which is what you want to lead you to desired cell.

`=MATCH(1, (sheet2!A$3:A$6=A3) * (NOT(ISBLANK(sheet2!H$3:H$6))))` gets you the index to the first hit, which is 4, and using that as in index into H$3:H$6 gets you all the way home.

But I’d exploit the more useful features of XLOOKUP instead and I resort to index/match only when required—which is pretty rare now that XLOOKUP exists:

```
=XLOOKUP( 1, (sheet2!A$3:A$6=A3) * 
(NOT(ISBLANK(sheet2!H$3:H$6)))), sheet2!H$3:H$6)
```

One fewer functions, AND it adds the ability to handle a not-found condition.

This all *should* still work if you just decided to use A:A and H:H as in your previous formula.